# Is there a historical precedent of POTUS barring entry to the White House based on the prospective visitor's criticism of the President?

Tags: united-states, president

Also, what is the mechanism in place to enforce current POTUS recent withdrawn invitation of NBA team communicated via a free microblogging service?

(I'm assuming the president does not personally vet the guest list, and those who approve the list do not have "Recent twitter war?" on their checklist).

Comment: No one's under a legal obligation here, so what's there to enforce?  It's a pure publicity stunt on all sides.  Or would have been. The title question is interesting.

Comment: Well if you take a broad enough reading of the title question the secret service apparently keeps lists of people who send death threats.

Comment: Why do you assume that the President does not personally decide who to invite, or in this case, not to invite?

Comment: I think Nancy Reagan (as FLOTUS) decided to un-invite some poets to the White House. Can't find a reference to it though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cursory googling yields several examples of people being barred entry from the White House, and I'd gather there are many more that weren't newsworthy. Among these examples:

- [Gerry Adams](https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2016/mar/16/gerry-adams-expresses-anger-after-being-denied-entry-to-white-house) had been refused entry in March 2016. The White House cited security reasons and later excused themselves citing 'administrative input error'.
- Two British tourists were [denied entry](http://newsfeed.time.com/2012/01/31/british-tourists-tweets-get-them-denied-entry-to-the-u-s/) over a trivial joke on Twitter: "Free this week for a quick gossip/prep before I go and destroy America?"
- In the mid 1960s a [journalist from The Nation](http://law.justia.com/cases/federal/appellate-courts/F2/569/124/35083/) was denied entry, resulting in a lawsuit.

They seem more or less motivated by security concerns (however stretched), rather than reactions to outright criticism. (Though that last journalist example might warrant digging a bit deeper.)

Comment: Lol, don't think threatening to destroy America constitutes a trivial joke